# how to perform CDI of POJO's into beans in Java EE container without @Inject annotation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, cdi, inject

**Q1)** It is mentioned in the JavEE 7 tutorial that CDI injections can happen only in container manager objects such as servlets, EJB's and managed bean. Does it mean that I cannot do `CDI injection` in a `JAX-RS`?

**Q2)** I remember reading in some blog (dont know exactly which one) that with Java EE 7 any POJO objects can be injected anywhere within the container, since the container will "look" for them and initialize. Is that true?

**Q3)**

To inject an EJB into another bean, one would do

public class MainBean {

```
@EJB
UserDao userDao;
```

}

If I have the following POJO's objects

```
@ThirteenDigits
public class Thirteendigitgenerator implements NumberGenerator { ...}


@FourDigits
public class FourDigitsgenerator implements NumberGenerator { ... }
```

I ignored the Qualifiers for `@ThirteenDigits` and `@FourDigits` here.

If I want to inject above `ThirteenDigit POJO` into a bean,
I would do

```
@Inject @ThirteenDigits
NumberGenerator numbergenerator;
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do the following:

```
@ThirteenDigits
NumberGenerator numbergenerator;
```

Comment: Why are you wanting to avoid the annotation? And other containers, such as Spring, support `@Inject`; the warning is simply that you need machinery to interpret the annotation, and it's not magic.

Comment: @chrylis: I agree with you. but I would like to know if it is possible..

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking about. Can you give a more specific example about these "floating objects"?

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to do injection without "@inject" for a POJO, like the example I gave above. plus thoughts on the bottom part of the question

Comment: You could probably try to use beanManager api instead of annotations. Check this maybe it will be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420070/how-to-create-and-destroy-cdi-weld-managed-beans-via-the-beanmanager