# Create Beans Manually in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly

Short version: I want to be able to manually instantiate and control the lifecycle of statefull beans in Wildfly.

Long version:
I have a system that instantiates several different models of a system.  These beans are all instantiated as singleton beans so they can keep their state and take inputs as a group.  They are always looked up as a group with

```
@Inject
@Any
Instance<BusinessInterface> businessBeans;
```

which allows me to pas them all input as a group and collect their data as a group.  It also means that I can deploy new singleton beans/models and they get pulled into the workflow dynamically.  I don't have any need to ever look up any specific models/beans.

Now, for the problem that anyone with experience sees coming from a mile away:  a new requirement means that I need to be able to deploy multiple copies of each model.  But they're singletons.  Is there a way to make this work?  I feel like there must be a way for me to manually instantiate beans that won't die until I kill them, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I presume you didn't mean stateful sessionbeans, but common CDI-beans having instance variables (state). There are  (dangerous) ways to instantiate CDI-Beans manually during runtime, but imhO no way to have the businessBeans-collection automatically extended by these manually instantiated beans.

Comment: @aschoerk Can you share?  Maybe it will at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: lookup BeanManager.createCreationalContext that should  give you more details. But beware memory-leaks can happen

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420070/how-to-create-and-destroy-cdi-weld-managed-beans-via-the-beanmanager helps