# How to make a CDI bean lazily initialized?

Tags: spring, cdi, lazy-initialization

I am using Weld implementation of CDI 1.0 and I cannot find way how to make bean lazy like in Spring (using `@Lazy` or `lazy-init` in XML). Is there a way how to tell CDI's `Injector` not to initialize bean on startup?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920758/java-ee-6-inject-lazy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this isn't possible in CDI. The closest thing you could get would be to create a new InjectionPoint (using an Extension) implementation that gives a proxy and the proxy would initialize everything on the first method invocation.

Comment: So, by using @Inject Instance<beantype> beantypeProvider; this should work right ?

Comment: Um, my first reaction is to say that might work. Though if you're using a CDI 1.0 implementation Instance does leak memory of dependant scoped instances.

Comment: Which implementation are you talking about ? where is your reference ?

Comment: Both OWB and Weld had the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385190/cdi-application-and-dependent-scopes-can-conspire-to-impact-garbage-collection for more information. It was a both a spec and an implementation issue.

Comment: So, as long as I can use the Instance.destroy(instance) I am ok :) Thanks

Answer (score 8):

See my answer on: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/lazy_injection_with_javax_inject

Using

```
 @Inject
Instance<MyObject> object;
```

the bean is initialized only when needed ... isn't that what you want?

Comment: [According to Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry), there's an alternative to this that _might_ be a little more lightweight: merely injecting a `Provider<?>` instead of an `Instance<?>`, all the rest being the same.

Comment: @Hein Blöd The link to the entry in Adam Bien's weblog has changed to [Lazy Injection with javax.inject.Provider](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/lazy_injection_with_javax_inject).

Answer (score 5):

If the bean you're injecting is in a normal scope (@SessionScoped, @RequestScoped etc), it will be lazily instantiated. What you get in your client bean is a proxy that doesn't point to a concrete instance until the first time you invoke a method on the proxy.

As others have already pointed out, `@Inject Instance<MyBean> myBeanInstance;` can also be used to establish an explicit lazy instantiation.