# Java EE 6 @Inject lazy?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, java-ee-6, cdi, inject

I am doing some refactoring and reviewing of the application that we are currently developing.  While doing this I found that more beans are injected and I think making they loading in an lazy manner would be better suited for their purpose. I am using Java EE 6 and tend to use more CDI than EJB injection.

So the question is whether it is possible to inject the beans lazily and if so, how can you do it?

Comment: yes, that pretty much answers my question - it's not possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What about using

```
@Inject
private Instance<?> lazyProvider;
```

?

That allows Getting instance of "?" when actually needed via

```
lazyProvider.get();
```

Comment: I have to try it, sounds promising. And how do I say what type I want to get?

Comment: Instance is a generic type. So when you inject an Instance<Foo>, get() will return a Foo.

Comment: Ok, how do I inject Foo for instance? Where do I decide what to inject?

Comment: Just like you would do with Foo itself. By default, you will get a new instance with dependent scope. But you could also (by using a producer or annotating the Foo.class) define custom scope and injection behavior.