# Spring boot - import jar but not all its beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hello I have a "common" project which contains all the implementations of various queues I use.

I use 2 queues in my flow due to legacy.

It has Kafka and rabbit.

My project defines 2 beans and sub-beans:

- KafkaProducer
- KafkaConsumer
- RabbitQueue

All containing some sub-beans to handle failures and stuff.

Now this is my questions:
I have one microservice that does not use Kafka.  I only want to define the Rabbit queue and its beans, but once I import this common jar dependency, It automatically initiates the Kafka beans.

How can this be done in spring without separating to different libraries.

For example:

```
@Componenet
public class KafkaProducer {

   @Inject
   private KafkaFailureHandler failureHandler;

}
```

Regards,
Ido

Comment: can you exclude them in componentscan?

Comment: Did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Add [@Lazy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation to class

> If present and set to true, the @Bean or @Component will not be initialized until referenced by another bean or explicitly retrieved from the enclosing BeanFactory.

About [lazy @Inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630508/how-to-make-a-cdi-bean-lazily-initialized), try adding inside `Instance<>`:

```
@Inject
Instance<KafkaFailureHandler> failureHandler;
```

Or by [Provider](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/lazy_injection_with_javax_inject)

```
@Inject
Provider<KafkaFailureHandler> failureHandler;
```

> For on-demand injection of components / resources inject them as Provider